# hiding directory name in the URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

my site's directory is:

```
localhost/

    includes/
        includes/initialize.php
        includes/user.php
        includes/session.php
        includes/database.php

    public/
        public/bootstrap/
        public/css/
        public/js/
        public/dashboard/index.php
        public/index.php

    .htaccess(first htaccess file)

 {
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [QSA,L]
     </IfModule>
 }
```

I'd like to have my url more neat, for example

when I type this: `http://localhost` I know it goes to `http://localhost/public/`
but the URL still is `http://localhost`

but the problem is when I type `http://localhost/dashboard`
unfortunately the URL will be `http://localhost/public/dashboard/` on my browser.

I do not want to see the word **public**.

I think I should have another htaccess file under the public directory, but I do not know the suitable code for it.

Comment: Can you influence your server configuration?

Comment: You should configure your server, and define the webroot to be your `public` folder.

Comment: I'm trying my codes on the XAMPP, I want to get out of this problem via just using .htaccess

Comment: Could you show your .htaccess file content..

Comment: I've written at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^public/ /public%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```

Comment: Do you also have a `dashboard/.htaccess`? OR `dashboard/index.php` doing URL change using some code?

Comment: no I don't, my dashboard/index.php does not any special function.

Comment: Only thing I can say is to run your request in Firebug and see what you get in Net tab. You can also try using a different browser to avoid 301 caching issues.